# PHP SQL Query ORDER by - Syntax-Mistake?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to order the following query by id desc (it's a column in the "check_todo"-table). Can anybody help me? :)

```
$todo_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM check_todo WHERE id=".$row2->todo." ORDER by id DESC");
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_object($todo_query))
    {
```

it's not duplicate and it is not because of the reserved word. It doesn't work with "id" oder "placeholder" (both columns in check_todo) either...

Comment: what error your geting ?

Comment: Add the error massage

Comment: there is no error.. it just does not sort the list...

Comment: it's not duplicate and it is not because of the reserved word. It doesn't work with "id" oder "placeholder" (both columns in check_todo) either...

Comment: What does `$row2->todo` contain? The data should escaped with `mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $row2->todo) ` when using it in the query, unless you have validated it to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

[`TYPE` is a reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).
Add backticks around it:

```
$todo_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM check_todo WHERE id=".$row2->todo . 
      " ORDER by `type` ASC");
```

Comment: doesn't work.. textmate shows me "Order" as a syntax-error (wrong color)

Comment: I'm not responsible for the colors in your code editor.

Comment: sure you are not :) only wanted to say, that it still doesn't work.

Comment: According to the link you posted, TYPE is not a reserved word.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Check again the link. It is in the rightmost column.

Comment: `ORDER by id DESC` doesn't work either..

Comment: Why a downvote now?